# Bootstrap Collapse menu not collapsing?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Ok My Site is freaking done!! I just have to make my menu responsive.... and the hover effects on my site won't allow the links to be responsive so I want to make this a collapse menu but for some reason its not working. I displays properly but once I go to view it on my mobile device it shows the button with the bars in it but it doesn't toggle my menu can you help me figure out what's wrong?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
           <div class="container-fluid">

                    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2"></div>

                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8" style=" border-radius:5px; border-bottom-color:Silver; border:3px; border-top-color: transparent !important; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.8)">
                  <div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#homenav">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
  </button>
  </div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="homenav">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav"> 
<li><a href="pages/home.html" class="menu_nav demo-4">
  <span>
    <span>Home</span>
    <span>-Home-</span>
    <span></span>
  </span>
</a></li>

      <li> <a href="pages/artist.html" class="menu_nav demo-4">
  <span>
    <span>Roster</span>
    <span>-Roster-</span>
    <span></span>
  </span>
</a></li>
<li>
<a href="pages/order.html" class="menu_nav demo-4">
  <span>
    <span>Brands</span>
    <span>-Brands-</span>
    <span></span>
  </span>
</a>    
       </li> <li>
      <a href="pages/music.html" class="menu_nav demo-4">
  <span>
    <span>Music</span>
    <span>-Music-</span>
    <span></span>
  </span>
</a>    
       </li>     
        <li>
      <a href="pages/videos.php" class="menu_nav demo-4">
  <span>
    <span>Videos</span>
    <span>-Videos-</span>
    <span></span>
  </span>
</a> </li>
<li>
<a href="pages/videos.php" class="menu_nav demo-4">
  <span>
    <span>Store</span>
    <span>-Store-</span>
    <span></span>
  </span>
</a>    
</li>
<li>          
           <a href="pages/services.html" class="menu_nav demo-4">
  <span>
    <span>Services</span>
    <span>-Services-</span>
    <span></span>
  </span>
</a> 
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#" class="menu_nav demo-4">
  <span>
    <span>Resources</span>
    <span>-Resources-</span>
    <span></span>
  </span>
</a>       </li>

</ul>
        </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2"></div>




           </div>     
  </nav>
  <!--End Of Navigation-->
```

Comment: Check your console for errors and you'll see the issues. You're loading two version of jQuery, you only need one and use the newer one.

Comment: @vanburen I am using jquery 2.1.4

Comment: Again, check your console. You have v2.14 as the first script in your HEAD, then have v1.4.4 listed directly before BootstrapJS

Comment: DONE.!!!!! Didnt know I had another jquery in there... thx I works....

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing javascript files. Include this to your project and it should work.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I have them both included on my site still not working? could my ajax jquery be interfering? visit my website and see what I am talking about http://www.trillumonopoly.com

Comment: Wooow. So much errors. Go to your site and then open your console window. Chrome (Ctrl+Shift+I). The first one is about: "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 3"